# How to shorten salesforce site URL? If not can i host my visualforce & apex code if i purchase a new domain?

Tags: force.com-sites

I have created & registered a new domain through sites(by using developer edition), the URL is http://texmax-developer-edition.ap1.force.com
Is there any way to shorten the URL??
If not, can i host my visualforce & apex code if i purchase a new domain say www.texmax.com through godaddy.com or bigrock?

Comment: Also if your intention is just to shorten .Use https://bitly.com/ to shorten the URL.

Answer (score 6):

http://ap1.salesforce.com/help/doc/en/sites_overview.htm

http://ap1.salesforce.com/help/doc/en/salesforce_platform_portal_implementation_guide.pdf

You can achieve this in force.com sites .In your site configuration there is an option called Custom Web address.Here you can use your custom web address obtained from Godaddy.com.(Note this option is available only for Production).

1)The custom Web address acts as an alias to your Force.com address.

2)To enable a custom Web address, create a CNAME record to your Force.com
domain with that registrar.

3) If you have not registered this address, you encounter
Custom Web Address
an error. **Custom Web addresses aren't supported for Developer
Edition or sandbox organizations.**

Note: If you choose to create a branded top-level domain or subdomain
through a domain name registrar, the CNAME record that you provide
to that registrar must be your Force.com domain name and not the site
URL. For example, if you entered mycompany when registering your
Force.com domain, the CNAME must be mycompany.force.com
not the full value of the site URL.

NOTE:This does not work for https .

Comment: might be worth adding that that doesn't work for https

Comment: @Sdry Yes that i missed .Agreed !We have lot of post saying this does not work for https .

Comment: Thanks Mohit, suppose if i purchase a branded top level domain & as you said provide the cname as my force.com domain name & then try to navigate through different pages of my site, what will be the url like after different page/tab clicks? Will it point to my top level domain name or force.com URL?

Comment: It will be like www.texmax.com/home where home is your Visualforce page name

Comment: As an example, I built a quick a proof of concept here when they first released sites (http://www.bfcclient.com) - the about link works, but the other's don't, and you'll see a SFDC error appear - but it's 100% hosted by Force.com Sites

Comment: Don't name a sites page "home".  You'll get some interesting problems with deployments, since SF already has a page called home in the default portal.

Comment: @ShaneMcLaughlin Great advice .Just as an example i had suggested .Good to know it creates deployment problems